# Почему не работает border-collapse и border-spacing?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

Не работает `border-collapse` и `border-spacing`.
Как это исправить?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #111111;
}

table {
  width: 600px;
}

th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 7 px 10px 10px 10px;
}

th {
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.grey {
  background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.1);
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.money {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Название</th>
    <th class="money">Зарегистрированная цена</th>
    <th class="money">Текущая ставка</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grey">
    <td>Matt Stone, Trey Parker</td>
    <td>South Park</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="money">500 000$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sony</td>
    <td>PS4</td>
    <td class="money">100 000$</td>
    <td class="money">1000000$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="grey">
    <td>Microsoft</td>
    <td>Xbox One</td>
    <td class="money">100 000$</td>
    <td class="money">521 600$</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse;` - для таблицы, а не для ячеек

Comment: Забыл дописать, что `border-spacing` не будет работать, если `border-collapse` со значением `collapse`, но это и так должно быть понятно.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо. Да мне действительно итак понятно, что border-spacing не будет работать, если border-collapse со значением collapse))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не работает и не должен в этом случае, так как вы применили это свойство к ячейкам, а оно должно было быть примененным к таблице в целом.

`border-collapse` - устанавливает, как отображать границы вокруг ячеек таблицы. Это свойство играет роль, когда для ячеек установлена рамка, тогда в месте стыка ячеек получится линия двойной толщины. Значение `collapse` заставляет браузер анализировать подобные места в таблице и убирать в ней двойные линии. При этом между ячейками остаётся только одна граница, одновременно принадлежащая обеим ячейкам. То же правило соблюдается и для внешних границ, когда вокруг самой таблицы добавляется рамка.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #111111;
}
table {
    width: 600px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
   }
th, td {
    padding: 7 px 10px 10px 10px;
   }
th {
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
   }
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
   }
tr.grey {
    background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.1);

   }
tr:hover {
    background-color: khaki;
   }
.money {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Название</th>
    <th class="money">Зарегистрированная цена</th>
    <th class="money">Текущая ставка</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="grey">
    <td>Matt Stone, Trey Parker</td>
    <td>South Park</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="money">500 000$</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Sony</td>
    <td>PS4</td>
    <td class="money">100 000$</td>
    <td class="money">1000000$</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="grey">
    <td>Microsoft</td>
    <td>Xbox One</td>
    <td class="money">100 000$</td>
    <td class="money">521 600$</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Обратите внимание на комментарии @Deonis по поводу работы данного свойства.

*Ссылки:*

[О свойстве border-collapse на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)
[CSS border-collapse Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)
[W3.org про border-collapse](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-border-collapse)